# elections.stackexchange.com isn't loading

Tags: bug, election-page

I can't connect to http://elections.stackexchange.com or https://elections.stackexchange.com — the initial connection times out every time. I check this every week, and it worked fine last time, so it must be something pretty recent. (Further HTTPS deployment?)

Comment: StackOverflow and Workplace have been loading very slowly for me over the past hour. I'm guessing something in *the stack* is running slowly today.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yeah, this is gonna be down for a bit; Tim Stone was maintaining it and Tim Post was hosting it. The domain, of course, was controlled by the company... Which is currently moving all se.com subdomains to HTTPS. This presents two problems:

1. Tim Post can't continue hosting it, and we don't have an internal setup for hosting node.js apps.
2. We can't keep it on that domain.

We're gonna try & figure *something* out, but don't expect it to be back for a little while.

Comment: I can host it, but we'll get into the domain logistics issue we had before. Available to chat about the options more whenever there's time

Comment: 6-8 weeks, months, or years?

Comment: I'd guess hosting is probably the *lesser* problem here, @Tim (although it is the one that's most immediately relevant). Once Tim's caught up on stuff you two can figure it out.

Comment: Maybe if this only page would remain on http until the problem isn't solved?

Comment: You navigated me from the post to here and when I reached here, you are here. :d

Comment: It seems it's still not up, where do SE elections happen now ?

Comment: @GypsyCosmonaut: Elections, now and in the past, have always happened on the sites. Those are not broken, and they still display their somewhat scanty information. It's the augmented election info site, which had a lot of collected statistics and links for candidates, that no longer functions.

Comment: I know there are a few elections going on this quarter... any update on this tool?

Comment: Not from me I'm afraid, @LShaver - I'd built a prototype for internal use, but someone else will need to carry that forward.

Comment: @LShaver The link from ArtOfCode's answer seems to be working: https://artofcode.co.uk/elections Not official or anything, but it gives you the info.

Answer (score 11):

So this has been down for long enough and bugging me enough that I made a new one. It's not a direct copy, mainly because I didn't have a good enough reference, but it does similar things. You can find it here:

> ## [artofcode.co.uk/elections](https://artofcode.co.uk/elections)

The source for it is [on GitHub](https://github.com/Charcoal-SE/elections), if you're interested.

Comment: The [source code is available](https://github.com/tms/stack-election) for the original one if there's any particular aspect you had wanted to reference

Comment: Mostly just the look and feel, @TimStone - I ended up using Stacks instead, but I might well have a poke around to see what I can scavenge :)