# Remove link to elections.se from all network sites which conducted an election

Tags: feature-request, bug, election, link-rot

As can be seen in [elections.stackexchange.com isn't loading](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/294719/elections-stackexchange-com-isnt-loading), the site http://elections.stackexchange.com/ is closed until further notice (which can take long weeks/months) hence all the links pointing to it are dead.

I would like to suggest removing the dead links from the election results page in Stack Exchange sites, e.g. on [Travel.SE site](https://travel.stackexchange.com/election/3):

> [image: Screenshot with link circled]

The link *More Information about the candidates* points to the URL http://elections.stackexchange.com/#travel.stackexchange which returns a 404.

> [image]

Comment: It is https fault.

Comment: Can you link the actual page you see that link on?

Comment: It is there between the 2 images @PatrickHofman

Comment: I mean the page on Travel.SE.

Comment: @Patrick https://travel.stackexchange.com/election/3

Comment: https://travel.stackexchange.com/election/2

Comment: Yeah, all election results pages, all over Stack Exchange.

Comment: Note that [the site was hacked](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89?m=5961318#5961318) shortly after the HTTPS switch, and has since been disabled until a new (secure) hosting solution can be found.