# Is there a way to see election summaries across Stack Exchange?

Tags: feature-request, election

I know that there are currently elections happening on [Workplace.SE](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/election?cb=1) and [Sustainability.SE](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/election?cb=1). A while back there was a meta post (["Experimenting with Pro Tempore elections"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314459/experimenting-with-pro-tempore-elections)) indicating that a lot of sites would be having elections around roughly the same time.

I tried to see if there was a tool to find out about elections across SE -- apparently [there used to be one, but it's broken now](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/294723/346823).

**How can I find a schedule of elections, or a list of all sites currently having elections?** Ideally this would be a tool that remains up-to-date, and not just a list of sites in a static answer here.

Comment: https://artofcode.co.uk/elections

Comment: Why not this one: https://artofcode.co.uk/elections set up by user https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/262823/artofcode from https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/325076/300925  I saw your comment on the answer but it is up to date, it even has one starting in 6 days at https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/election

Comment: @MarkKirby looks like at some point between my comment there 39 minutes ago, and your comment 13 minutes ago, it started working again!

Comment: Related: [OBSOLETE - Elections Statistics page for Stack Exchange sites](https://stackapps.com/q/2049)